# How to inactivate a JIRA status workflow?

Tags: workflow, jira

I have created a workflow of changing status in JIRA but now I want some of the statuses to be deleted. It does not give me the option to delete. I read in the document that you cannot delete active workflow steps.

How can I inactivate a workflow is not described anywhere. I have spent hours on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I got you 100% right, but to delete a workflow you have to unassign it from the workflow scheme, which is only possible if that scheme is not used by any project. If a status is not used anymore in any workflow it can be deleted if I remember correctly.

How I do it in most cases is: I create a new workflow, as it is needed. Then I associate it to the project. Afterwards I can delete the old one.